# regex pattern lowercase and uppercase and number OR special character

Tags: regex

Currently i have the following regex pattern:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}
```

which is at least one lowercase, one uppercase, one number and one special character.
How can I make the special characters **optional**?

Comment: Could you show us examples of input strings and the associated expected outputs?

Comment: Incidentally, the duplicated `$` in your special characters list is redundant.  You can use `[$@!%*?&]` and `[A-Za-z\d$@!%*?&]`

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make the special characters optional?

Just remove lookahead to check for special char:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}$
```

Also it is safer to use end anchor `$` in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you need is a `?` after `[$@$!%*?&]`

Your regex should be `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&]?)[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}`

https://regex101.com/r/1V8Xsq/1

Comment: `(?=.*[$@$!%*?&]?)` can be shortened to . (That is, to nothing.)

Comment: @melpomene Agreed.  The whole `(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])` can be removed as it's a positive lookahead that is now optional.  `.*` can match nothing and `[$@$!%*?&]?` can match nothing, so the whole lookahead is kind of pointless `(?=.*)`.  Good point.