# Using regex and the | operator

Tags: c#, regex, unity-game-engine, operator-keyword

So I'm using Regex to create a change password form. Some text updates to "weak", "average", "strong" and "perfect" based on the passwords strength. I've managed to create a regex string that checks for all characters active as you can see in this string here which I would then compare with the new password string...

```
Regex rgxAll = new Regex(@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$");
```

Though what I'm trying to do now is create a string that checks: "Does the new password contain a lowercase character AND an uppercase character OR a special character OR a number" So to simplify it into coding terms...

```
NewPass.IsMatch(lowercaseLetter &&(uppercaseLetter || specialChar || number);
```

So yeah, I'm looking to create a regex that I can use IsMatch on to check. I've tried looking online but the syntax of regex is confusing to me.

Comment: Put those patterns you ORed into 1 lookahead.

Comment: How would that look? Sorry I'm not familiar with Regex at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex pattern lowercase and uppercase and number OR special character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883854/regex-pattern-lowercase-and-uppercase-and-number-or-special-character)

Comment: Just a note on style, I wouldn't use "perfect". ;)

Comment: I have just thought about a pattern like `^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[a-z]*[^a-z]).*` - it will require at least 1 lowercase and at least 1 char other than lowercase ASCII letter. It is not quite the same but might be something you can consider.

Comment: You should read [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a single match expression per character class and then use standard boolean expressions to combine them:

```
var upper   = Regex.IsMatch(password, @".*[A-Z].*");
var lower   = Regex.IsMatch(password, @".*[a-z].*");
var digit   = Regex.IsMatch(password, @".*\d.*");
var special = Regex.IsMatch(password, @".*[\W_].*");

var passwordAccepted = lower && (upper || special || digit);
```

Which also allows you to give the user feedback *why* his password was rejected:

```
if(!digit)
{
    Console.Writeline("password must contain a number!")
}
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z\W\d_])
```

Exp:

- `(?=.*[a-z])` : lookahead for lowercase letter
- `(?=.*[A-Z\W\d_])` : lookahead for uppercaseLetter || specialChar || number

Comment: Note that this regex misses `_` that is considered a special char and is present in the original regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah.. missed that.. updated now :)